# Oracle SQL Subquery with MAX Function in Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working off of an Oracle DB with Oracle SQL Developer.  I have two queries.  I need to change Query #1 so that it retrieves the address demographic data from Query #2.  I believe I need to insert Query #2 into Query #1 so that it is a referenced subquery.  Query #2 selects data from a table called ADDRESS_EFF_DATE that stores records of address demographics. It has a record for each time an employee changes their address and the EFF_DATE column shows the date of the record.  I need to pull the most recent data, thus the subquery.  I am not sure how to do this.

Query #1

```
SELECT cd.ONECODE as "Client One Code"
        ,cs.REAL_SSN as "Employee SSN"
        ,cs.REAL_SSN as "Member SSN"
        ,'Subscriber' as "Person Type"
        ,eed.LAST_NAME as "Last Name"
        ,eed.FIRST_NAME as "First Name"
        ,eed.BIRTHDATE as MemberDOB
        ,eed.SEX as MemberGender
        ,aed.Address_1 as AddressLine1
        ,aed.Address_2 as AddressLine2
        ,aed.City
        ,aed.State
        ,aed.Zip as ZipCode
        ,aed.Country as CountryCode
        ,aed.Telephone as HomeNumber
        ,eed.EMAIL_ADDRESS as "Employee Emaill Address"
        ,eed.EFF_DATE as "Date Last Actively at Work"
        ,eed.LATEST_HIRE_DATE as "Employee Date of Hire"
        ,eed.LAST_TERM_DATE as "Employee Date of Termination"
        ,mcemd.RATE_1 as "Employee Salary"

        /*,MV_COMB_EMP_MAX_DTS.RATE_1 as "Employee Salary"*/

    FROM

    EMPLOYEE_EFF_DATE eed

    INNER JOIN ADDRESS_EFF_DATE aed 
        ON eed.ssn = aed.ssn
    INNER JOIN COMP_SSN cs
        ON cs.ssn = eed.ssn
    INNER JOIN COMPANY_DETAIL cd
        ON eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = cd.COMPANY_ID
    INNER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYMENT_DATA ced
        ON eed.SSN = ced.SSN
    INNER JOIN MV_COMB_EMP_MAX_DTS mcemd
        ON eed.SSN = mcemd.SSN
    WHERE eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 4029
    AND aed.ADDRESS_KEY = 0
```

Query #2

```
   SELECT aed.EFF_DATE
    ,aed.SSN
    ,aed.ADDRESS_KEY
    ,aed.Address_1 as AddressLine1
    ,aed.Address_2 as AddressLine2
    ,aed.City
    ,aed.State
    ,aed.Zip as ZipCode
    ,aed.Country as CountryCode
    ,aed.Telephone as HomeNumber
FROM ADDRESS_EFF_DATE aed
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SSN, ADDRESS_KEY, MAX(EFF_DATE) Eff_Date
    FROM ADDRESS_EFF_DATE
    GROUP BY SSN, ADDRESS_KEY
) aed2 ON aed.SSN = aed2.SSN AND aed.EFF_DATE = aed2.Eff_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (lazy) way is to join those two queries as "Table Expressions". For example:

```
select
  x.col1,
  y.col2
from (
  -- query #1 here
) x
join (
  -- query #2 here
) y 
on x.col1 = y.col2 -- join predicate here
```

You can also use CTEs, if you prefer.

Alternatively, you could try merging both queries into a single one; this could lead to better performance, but more work in terms of coding and debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am looking for the best way to merge these queries as I have a couple more subqueries that are similar that need to be merger.  Can you offer some guidance in that area?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have ADDRESS_EFF_DATE in your first query and you want to get the last address an employee has moved, you can do this in one query using DENSE_RANK. I suggest to implement it like this:

```
SELECT a."Client One Code",
   a."Employee SSN" ,
   a."Member SSN",
   a."Person Type",
   a."Last Name",
   a."First Name",
   a.MemberDOB,
   a.MemberGender,
   a.AddressLine1,
   a.AddressLine2,
   a.City,
   a.State,
   a.ZipCode,
   a.CountryCode,
   a.HomeNumber,
   a."Employee Emaill Address",
   a."Date Last Actively at Work",
   a."Employee Date of Hire",
   a."Employee Date of Termination",
   a."Employee Salary" FROM (
SELECT cd.ONECODE as "Client One Code"
    ,cs.REAL_SSN as "Employee SSN"
    ,cs.REAL_SSN as "Member SSN"
    ,'Subscriber' as "Person Type"
    ,eed.LAST_NAME as "Last Name"
    ,eed.FIRST_NAME as "First Name"
    ,eed.BIRTHDATE as MemberDOB
    ,eed.SEX as MemberGender
    ,aed.Address_1 as AddressLine1
    ,aed.Address_2 as AddressLine2
    ,aed.City
    ,aed.State
    ,aed.Zip as ZipCode
    ,aed.Country as CountryCode
    ,aed.Telephone as HomeNumber
    ,eed.EMAIL_ADDRESS as "Employee Emaill Address"
    ,eed.EFF_DATE as "Date Last Actively at Work"
    ,eed.LATEST_HIRE_DATE as "Employee Date of Hire"
    ,eed.LAST_TERM_DATE as "Employee Date of Termination"
    ,mcemd.RATE_1 as "Employee Salary"
    ,DENSE_RANK()  OVER (PARTITION BY eed.ssn ORDER BY aed.EFF_DATE DESC) AS drank
    /*,MV_COMB_EMP_MAX_DTS.RATE_1 as "Employee Salary"*/
FROM
EMPLOYEE_EFF_DATE eed
INNER JOIN ADDRESS_EFF_DATE aed 
    ON eed.ssn = aed.ssn
INNER JOIN COMP_SSN cs
    ON cs.ssn = eed.ssn
INNER JOIN COMPANY_DETAIL cd
    ON eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = cd.COMPANY_ID
INNER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYMENT_DATA ced
    ON eed.SSN = ced.SSN
INNER JOIN MV_COMB_EMP_MAX_DTS mcemd
    ON eed.SSN = mcemd.SSN
WHERE eed.P_COMPANY_ID_I = 4029
AND aed.ADDRESS_KEY = 0) a 
WHERE drank=1
```